# How to do column level permission with application custom user tables?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016, is there a way to do column level permission using custom application user/roles tables?

So the web application uses single user to authenticate/exec SQL to the database. And then the web framework selects from the custom user/role tables as defined by that web framework.

### Update

The user/roles are not SQL Server user/roles we are talking about user/roles of the application defined in custom user/roles tables. I was wondering if there's a way to integrate the two.

Comment: Column level permissions have existed long before SQL Server 2016. Can't actually find an example in the official Docs, but this displays the syntax for granting a user `SELECT` on a specific column: [Filtering SQL Server Columns Using Column Level Permissions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/). Note that that document is old and you should not be using `sp_addrolemember` any more. Use the `ALTER ROLE` syntax.

Comment: I mentioned the version just to be specific. But the feature you talk about is granting column permissions on SQL Server user. I should be more clear. I'm talking about application level users. I'll update my question.

Comment: How you "do" permissions with application-level users depends entirely on the framework you're using, since (usually) SQL Server isn't going to be passed information on what role is being used, unless the framework integrates it (with things like `SESSION_CONTEXT`). There are various ways to arrange that in SQL Server (stored procedures, custom views, custom schemas, or nothing at all and just doing all the filtering on the application side) but ultimately it's not up to SQL Server to arrange it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is right. Either you're using permissions based on roles within SQL Server, or roles built into the application. If the former, then the link above is what you're after, if the latter then that's up to **you** to define.

Comment: ok so if it's sp application sql then we have to use a bunch of if else or case when statements...